# Setting Up Apache Virtual Hosts on a Drive Other Than C:

Tags: apache, wamp, virtual-hosts

I've successfully set up virtual hosts before on my C: drive, but now I want to set some up on my D: drive. I follow the setup instructions [here](http://kristengrote.com/blog/articles/how-to-set-up-virtual-hosts-using-wamp), but when I click the WAMP icon to restart all services, the icon doesn't return to green.

Does anybody know what I need to do to get Virtual Hosts working on my D: drive? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Believe it or not, it looks like all I had to do was put quotes around the directory path:

```
<Directory "D:\Path\To\My\Directory">
    Order Deny,Allow  
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

I have no earthly idea why that fixes this problem, but I'll take it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `D:\` inside your `DocumentRoot`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>   
  DocumentRoot "D:\Users\Kristen\Documents\Projects\My Site" 
  ServerName mysite.local
</VirtualHost>
```

To find out why WAMP cannot restart, have a look at `error.log` inside the Apache folder.